I've trouble reading my properties when I create a native image with GraalVM | Problemas leyendo properties cuando creo imagen con GraalVM | Quarkus
I've some troubles reading my config properties during the creation of a native image with GraalVM when I get these values through a config server with these configurations:
package org.acme.config;

import lombok.Data;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

@Data
@Slf4j
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyPropertiesConfig {


    @ConfigProperty(name="url")
    private String url;

    @ConfigProperty(name="user.db")
    private String user;

    @ConfigProperty(name="pass.db")
    private String password;

}

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=##########
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=##########
quarkus.datasource.username=##########
quarkus.datasource.password=##########

quarkus.application.name=##########
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.enabled=true
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.url=##########
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.username=##########
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.password:##########
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.fail-fast=true
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.profiles=##########

        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigRecorder.validateConfigProperties(ConfigRecorder.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildStep$validateRuntimeConfigProperty1282080724.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildStep$validateRuntimeConfigProperty1282080724.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
        Suppressed: java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property url is required but it could not be found in any config source
                at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.convertValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:435)
                at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducerUtil.getValue(ConfigProducerUtil.java:100)
                at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigRecorder.validateConfigProperties(ConfigRecorder.java:60)
                ... 10 more
        Suppressed: java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property validacion.detalleTecnicoDefault is required but it could not be found in any config source

I try, a lot of things but no one fix that error. :c
I check quarkus logs and it says I'm reaching the configserver so idk what's going on

can you share a reproducer ?

Hi! @ozkanpakdil What do you mean by 'reproducer'? I'm sorry.

A small project with fully reproduce this issue. You can search in stackoverflow for examples

Of course, I'll prepare it
